# Why is biber so slow?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I have a simple document, about 20 pages long with some mathematics and a couple of tikz diagrams. I use biblatex and biber (0.9.9 MacTeX 2011) to compile my references, of which there are currently 2, with maybe 10 citations.

When using the bibtex backend the bibliography stage of my compilation takes under a second. Biber takes over 5 seconds to process exactly the same file.

I use TeXShop and with biber the console window appears but none of biber's command line output appears for at least 4 seconds.

Is there a problem with my setup or is biber slow by design?

EDIT: yes, it is slow every time. I've done some digging into the folders where biber unpacks its perl dependencies and I think TeXShop might be unpacking it every time. Perhaps something deletes the unpacked binary after each use.

The way I've made TeXShop use biber is to change the bibTeX engine field in the preferences to `biber'.

Comment: The first time you run Biber, it has to unpack a lot of Perl stuff. Second and subsequent runs should therefore be a lot faster than the first run. Do you see this issue repeatedly?

Comment: @JosephWright -- no question it speeds up, but it still runs slower than bibtex.  It's still worth it, given all the extra functionality, but there is a noticeable difference. (Same with luatex; and the two combined gives you time to grab a coffee for book-length projects.)

Comment: @jon, granted I know it will be slower that bibtex, but I've a speedy SSD and the document is so small I suspect something else is at play. It blazes through the LuaLatex compilation in about 1s.

Comment: On my system, Biber is certainly slower than BibTeX when run for example from the Terminal, with no graphical element and no unpacking (4.5 s _versus_ 0.3 s for the test file `biblatex-chem-acs`). I'm not sure you can say it's 'deliberate', but BibTeX is a small program written in (I think) C whereas Biber is more complex and written in Perl. I'm not sure what you can do here unless you are volunteering to work on the Biber codebase.

Comment: @JosephWright thanks for your own `benchmarks' it may just be that we pay for the extra features biber offers (UTF-8 yay!) with a couple of seconds of compilation. That's fine. If there's an effort to port biber to a (faster) programming language that I know, I'll see what I can do...

Comment: I don't really see the point porting to a faster language - it's a batch program after all. You will never get something as fast as bibtex but with 80% more functionality ... Of course it could be done in C but it would be a hell of a job.

Comment: @PLK Maybe even cross-compiling it to C might be worthwhile. The time difference yun described is harmless compared to my document where it's 0.3s for bibtex vs. 14s for biber. That's almost 50 times slower.

Comment: I know but for a batch processing system, who cares?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is slower than bibtex which is in C, even if you take into consideration the first run unpacking. Bear in mind that biber does a *lot* more than bibtex too. They are hardly comparable in functionality at all. Your tikz and maths should make no difference to biber. If your cache is getting deleted every time you run, this will make a huge difference. Easy to check this - delete the cache and run. Is the second biber run any faster?

The main overhead is sorting. It is a complex business, dealing with much more than bibtex - Unicode 7.0, direction per-field, case per field ... 
Next overhead is uniqueness processing. Again, complex. Bibtex probably does about 20% of what biber does. See the biber PDF manual to get a sense of its share of the biblatex work.

As of version 2.5 (currently in DEV), I have done some profiling with NYTProf. The majority of `biber`s time is spent inside the `Unicode::Collate` module (written in C), as one would expect as sorting is a main focus and it's expensive to do tailored UCA sorting (which `bibtex` doesn't even come close to doing). After some examining of the call stacks, I've done some loop tidying for sorting calls and now `biber` 2.5 is about four times as fast as 2.4 and probably all earlier versions.

As mentioned in the doc, for performance testing, I use a 2150 entry, 15,000 line .bib file which references a 630 entry macro file with a resulting 160 or so page bibliography. In `biber` 2.4 this takes about 2 minutes to process. In the current 2.5 development version it takes about 28 seconds. This is almost the same now as when using the `--fastsort` option which doesn't use Unicode collation (so I may drop `--fastsort` since it is functionally far less useful and if there is no performance benefit, there is no longer any point in it).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm not all that comfortable wiping files and folders from arcane /var directories. If someone could disambiguate the biber manual's description of where it gets unpacked for me I'll try deleting the cache. That should settle this once and for all.

Comment: It's quite safe to delete the par-xxxxx directory

Comment: I just tested biber on a little file with and without deleting the cache. I can report that there is no problem with cache persistence, it's just slow. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I will look more into optimisation at some point

Comment: @PLK This is not strictly related, but I have noticed that there is a bug that makes biber crash when some temporary files get messed up (I think it happens when you stop the compilation while biber is processing files, but I am not sure). Rebooting usually works, but is there a command line (or other) way of deleting the cache without rebooting (which I never do anymore)? Or a way of fixing the bug altogether?

Comment: This usually only happens if you stop biber on the first run after install of a new version. If the cache gets corrupted, you can just delete it and let bib run once without interruption. See the biber manual for the cache location. I will probably add a new option to print the cache location.

Comment: Try the biber 1.0 beta -it has a --cache option to show the cache location now. You will need to be using biblatex 2.0 beta

Comment: @PLK: I also experienced `biber` slowing down my whole compilation process a lot - are you aware of this question ( http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230796/4009 ) and my results in its answer and could you comment on that?

Comment: just as context: After 5 years in science my personal bibtex file weights about 22k lines with 1452 entries. With this reference and with taking into account that work groups often have shared bibtex files, the test file seems somewhat small.

Comment: I'm using biber 2.11 and it's still extremly slow. 
Sorting algorithms have evolved quite a lot and shouldn't have any problem sorting 10000 lines in much less than a second.

Comment: Can we replace the default perl.exe with other distribution such as Active Perl or something faster?

Comment: The sorting is done using a modern algorithm with custom cacheing, it has nothing to do with sorting. The main speed penalty is Unicode handling and sorting key generation and this is inevitable in any system that does complex Unicode handling. I can assure you short of rewriting everything in C (pointless anyway since all critical subcomponents - sorting, unicode collation etc. are already in C), there is no speeding such complex processing up. You can use any perl you want to run biber if you are not using the pre-packaged binaries.

Comment: I'm wondering whether sorting is really the issue here. I tried using some rfc.bib file containing about 8500 entries, of which I use exactly one (so no sorting is needed, right?). Just parsing it takes 12 seconds, how can that be? (I stopped the time between the `LaTeX decoding` and `Found BibTeX data source` output.)