# Should I move to biber? Should I move to biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

I've been using LaTeX and BibTeX since 1985. Over the past year or so I've noticed that a lot of the examples I'm finding online are using `biblatex`, a nearly complete reimplementation of BibTeX in LaTeX, and `biber`, another nearly complete reimplementation of BibTeX. I know that `biblatex` can be used with either `bibtex` or with `biber`. And all come with the standard LaTeX distribution now.

So my question:

- Should I move from `bibtex` and `pdflatex` to `biblatex`?
- Should I move from `bibtex` to `biber`?
- Should I move from `bibtex` to both `biblatex` and `biber`?
- What should I worry about?

Comment: If `bibTeX` is sufficient for your documents, why not stick to it?

Comment: See [What to do to switch to `biblatex`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/5764)

Comment: See also [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864). So if `bibtex` and friends still work for you, you should probably stick with it, especially if you submit your work to journals. Switching to `bilatex` with `bibtex` (and no `biber`) is in my mind not a good option.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/what-is-the-difference-between-bibtex-and-biblatex

Comment: Choosing `biblatex` means, nowadays, also using Biber, as there are many features of the package that BibTeX can't cope with.

Comment: @moewe There are perfectly good reasons for using `biblatex` with BibTeX (or rather not requiring BibTeX). You get the customisation in documents rather than needing to hack `.bst` files, and quite a lot of the useful stuff works without Biber.

Comment: @egreg Same comment to you as to moewe :-)

Answer (score 3):

Biber can only be used with `biblatex`. The traditional BibTeX approach with `\bibliographstyle` is incompatible with Biber. This means there is no moving from BibTeX to Biber without also moving to `biblatex`.

So your options are to use

- BibTeX with `\bibliographystyle`,
- `biblatex` with BibTeX, or
- `biblatex` with Biber.

Using `biblatex` with BibTeX gives you the worst of both worlds: Some fancy `biblatex` features are only available with Biber, while most – if not all – drawbacks of the `biblatex` approach are still present if you use BibTeX. (For example in [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) it really doesn't matter a great deal whether you use BibTeX or Biber as `biblatex` backend: The publisher will still have to use a different workflow for `biblatex` bibliographies.) The development of new `biblatex` features generally assumes Biber is being used as a backend. Sometimes it is possible to implement some of these features also with BibTeX as backend, but it is not top priority to find a way to do that if it is more tricky.

It is true that Biber is [generally slower than BibTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53247/35864) and [a bit more picky about your `.bib` files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497829/35864). I can't argue a lot against the fact that Biber is slower: I can only say that it is not necessary to run Biber every time you (re)compile your document. A build tool like `latexmk` will help you run Biber only if it is necessary. I see the fact that Biber is a bit more fussy about malformed `.bib` files as a plus, because in general  Biber only complains about things that are wrong, i.e. that could cause trouble also with BibTeX, it's just that you might not have realised that there is an issue.

So I believe that nowadays the choice should be between the classical BibTeX approach with `\bibliographystyle` on one side and `biblatex` with Biber on the other.

My usual advice is that there is no reason to switch to `biblatex` (+Biber) if you are happy with what BibTeX (w/ `\bibliographystyle`) can give you at the moment. `biblatex` is generally not that well liked by publishers (who often have their own `\bibliographystyle`s for BibTeX). Because it is still under active development it can sometimes be a bit of a pain if you want to use new features when you collaborate with others who are using older systems.

But there is a bunch of things that is so much easier with `biblatex` than with BibTeX: Mainly style adjustments, split bibliographies, on-the-fly data manipulation, ... If you need one of these features, then `biblatex` is usually your best bet of getting these things done.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864), it appears that I should not move to `biber` as I frequently submit to scientific journals.

However, it does seem that I should consider using `biblatex`.

Comment: Journals have fixed bibliography styles file anyway. So from your perspective it wouldn't matter if you emulate the journal style with biblatex or use directly bibtex. Your `.bib` file will be the same. The real power becomes evident when you design your own style just like you design your own template. Hence this shouldn't be a reason to stay away from biblatex and biber.

Comment: That's a reason not to submit documents to journals using `biblatex`, but has nothing to do with your own documents.

Comment: @percusse Well, I think you could run into problems if you started using `biblatex`-specific (such as `\bibrangedash`) commands in your `.bib` file, while still intending to use the same `.bib` file with `bibtex` (for journals, perhaps). No?

Comment: @JosephWright, what's that reason?

Comment: @Jubobs You shouldn't introduce range dashes or other nuances if the original style doesn't include them. The journal style should be followed faithfully (no matter how terrible they might be). So for scientific submissions emulation of the `.bst` file is wasted work if the journal doesn't support it unless you want to base your design over a journal style and customize it for your own templates. Hence, everytime a user asks a question about customizing a journal style for personal taste over a submission, I have a generic comment waiting for them :P

Comment: @percusse -- Depending on the context, I think there is more too it than you suggest.  `biblatex` encourages a much saner markup approach to many things that simply doesn't work in `BibTeX`; e.g., `title = {This Is a \mkbibquote{Complicated} Title},` --- which will correctly nest the quotation marks in a title field.  The solution, I think, is *not* to not use those things in your `bib` file, but to create a dummy `.sty` file (say `bibtex-compatibility.sty`) to load that defines such commands for when you need to use BibTeX.  Then you can still use `biber+biblatex` for other projects.

Comment: @jon You simply can't submit that syntax to a journal. It will create problems. You have to fall back to bibtex.

Comment: @percusse -- Can you give an example?  I thought this is what `@preamble{...}` tricks were for.  (I ask only out of curiosity: no journal I submit to will accept any form of TeX, let alone any BibTeX/Biber compatibility issues?)

Comment: @jon, most Elsevier journals accept LaTeX. You upload the .tex files and they run pdflatex on their backend. It's pretty neat.

Comment: @vy32 -- True, but the only journal they publish that I know of that is also a viable venue for me is 'History of European Ideas' (there may be others).  If I ever try to publish there, I will be very happy *not* to need to convert to MS Word!

Comment: Several journals I use require MSWord. I usually prepare the manuscript with LaTeX and then convert to RTF using `latex2rtf`.