# How do I get biblatex to skip over incorrect BibTeX entries like bibtex always has?

Tags: biblatex, errors, biber

I have for three decades now kept notes in my BibTeX file. Unfortunately, I have to use `biblatex` in order to get footcite. I just want `biblatex` to skip over anything, that is not a properly formatted BibTeX entry. If there's a filter, I can use to just extract all the proper BibTeX entries from my file, I don't mind taking the time to make an intermediate file.

Note that BibTeX, once it recognises it can't parse something, will bail and look for the next `newline-@`.

That's all I need and can't believe, it hasn't already been written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several reasons why Biber is a bit more fussy about `.bib` files than BibTeX. I'll list a few possible stumbling blocks for Biber that are usually not that much of an issue (if at all) for BibTeX and where possible try to explain why there is a difference and try to suggest a cure.

Before we plunge in, we should note that people often use Biber synonymous with `biblatex`+Biber and BibTeX synonymous with `\bibliographystyle`+BibTeX (for the differences see also [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864)). `biblatex` can be used with BibTeX as backend instead of Biber, even though that is explicitly discouraged now, since many advanced features are only available with Biber. Some of the limitations discussed here are limitations of `biblatex` and its approach to bibliographies, those will occur regardless of the backend (BibTeX or Biber). Some limitations are specifically linked to Biber (the program) and will not appear with BibTeX (even in a `biblatex` setting). In the following I will try to make clear if something is a `biblatex` issue or a Biber issue, but I will always refer to the alternative as BibTeX, even though there should probably be a distinction between BibTeX (the program) and 'the BibTeX way of producing bibliographies on a fundamental level/the LaTeX side'. There is quite some variability in the `.bst` styles available for BibTeX, in the following we will usually assume a style that works similar to `plain.bst` or one of the `natbib` standard styles.

The general relevance and job description of BibTeX and Biber are discussed brilliantly in [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864), so I suggest to check out that post if you are not quite sure why you even need to run BibTeX or Biber. The short of it is that BibTeX and Biber make the data in the `.bib` file accessible to LaTeX and perform some processing steps that would be hard to do directly in LaTeX (with BibTeX that is mainly sorting and some label generation, Biber also calculates uniqueness information and a few other handy things).  The LaTeX-digestible data is written to the `.bbl` file.

## `.bbl` files

Where BibTeX (in the sense of the BibTeX way of producing bibliographies with `.bst` files/`\bibliographystyle`, as for example used with `natbib`) and `biblatex` differ fundamentally is in the format of the LaTeX-digestible `.bbl` file they produce. The `.bbl` file produced by BibTeX usually contains text that is ready-to-typeset in a `thebibliography` environment. If one were to write the bibliography manually, one would probably come up with code that looks similar to the output produced by BibTeX. (There are some BibTeX styles that go a bit further and use more complex macros to allow the user to change more aspects of the style on the fly. You can read more about this and see some examples in the background section of my answer to [Customize citation with bibulous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459161/35864).) The `.bbl` file is simply read in and typeset as normal LaTeX code by the `\bibliography` command and produces a complete bibliography (LaTeX doesn't know about the contents of the entries, it just typesets them). `biblatex`'s `.bbl` files, on the other hand, don't contain ready-to-typeset code, they contain the complete entry data and some additional info in a structured and LaTeX-readable way (again, an example of what that looks like can be found in [Customize citation with bibulous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459161/35864)). The `.bbl` for `biblatex` is read at the beginning of the document in its entirety so that all entry data is available throughout the entire document (so LaTeX 'knows' about the entry data of each item).

### Invalid LaTeX code in fields

The difference between `.bbl` files already explains a first reason for why BibTeX is more tolerant about certain things than `biblatex`. With the BibTeX approach only the data that is actually supposed to be printed in the bibliography is passed on to LaTeX (modulo `jurabib`), while with `biblatex` all known fields are passed on to LaTeX. Issues associated with malformed `abstract` fields often fall into the category of problems caused by this fact. Sometimes the `abstract` field of `.bib` files exported from a website contains invalid LaTeX code (cf. [Software-generated bibliographic entries: common errors and other mistakes to check before use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864)), for example an unescaped `%` or `#` character. For BibTeX users this is usually not an issue, since the abstract field is rarely typeset in the bibliography and thus rarely included in the `.bbl` file and seen by LaTeX. BibTeX unlike LaTeX does not have any issues with unescaped `%` and `#`, so everything goes smoothly. But for `biblatex` `abstract` is a known field, which means that it is passed on to LaTeX and read in at the beginning of the document. Unescaped `#` and `%` can the wreak havoc and cause errors. The field is read in even if it is never used and even if the user does not intend to use it. A possible remedy here is to tell Biber to remove the `abstract` field before it gets to the `.bbl` file, see [Error with percent sign in bib entry field when using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22179/35864).

## `btparse`

Biber is based on the Perl module [Text::BibTeX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::BibTeX), which in turn relies on the C library `btparse` to parse `.bib` files. There are some subtle differences between what `btparse` accepts as valid input and what BibTeX accepts. For example `btparse` does not allow `()` in entry keys, but BibTeX is fine with them (see [Using BibTeX keys containing parentheses with Biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96454/35864)).

BibTeX sometimes still tries to produce output even when there is an error whereas Biber will simply abort processing the entry in question or worse the complete run. Often the BibTeX output will be nonsensical in those cases, but the BibTeX error message is not very intrusive and I can imagine it may fall through the cracks especially when your editor digests the log messages for you. There is not a lot you can do here save for rewriting Biber or the underlying parsing library.

## File encodings

BibTeX only understands ASCII, whereas Biber has full Unicode support and can read files in other encodings as well. When BibTeX encounters non-ASCII chars, they are usually passed through unchanged, but in some situations (sorting mainly) the result may not be as desired. Biber on the other hand, can read and understand files in a variety of encodings (non-ASCII chars can be sorted according to a specified locale etc.). That means that the `.bib` files must be correctly encoded in the encoding expected by Biber (usually `biblatex` assumes the `.bib` file has the same encoding as the `.tex` file as declared to `inputenc` or dictated by the Engine; of course the automatic detection can be overridden with `bibencoding`): Files with mixed encoding may fail or come out as garbage. In this case the only solution is to make sure the file uses the specified encoding correctly.

## `--nodieonerror`

Biber has the option `--nodieonerror` which allows it to proceed past some errors that would normally abort a Biber run. In practice this is helpful for a certain class of errors produced by the underlying `btparse` library, which sometimes can be skipped over, but it may well happen that going past an error causes a crash or nonsensical output. So this is something I would use only for debugging and I wouldn't expect wonders.

Comment: Thanks! This is great! My problem is indeed that I have accreted multiple file encodings over time. Is there a tool that will quickly strip out anything that isn't just ascii, like bibtex does? Any citation I actually use I have converted to ascii mark up, I never rely on unicode.

Comment: @JoannaBryson BibTeX doesn't strip anything non-ASCII it just passes it through unchanged. That means that sorting based on those characters is probably wrong and means that things will explode if LaTeX can't deal with those characters. Since Biber can't handle malformed files you need to remove the incorrect encoding with an external tool before Biber processes the file. I assume there are many ways to do that (I would have probably used Notepad++), e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/475548. Just search the web a bit.

Comment: I'm going to say you answered this, but to be honest we just had to write an R program to do what bibtex does and create a new .bib file that biblatex could read.

Comment: @JoannaBryson If you think your R script is useful for other people, you might as well write an answer of your own and tell us about the script. Out of curisosity: What exactly do you mean by doing what BibTeX does? Do you mean that you wrote a program that parses `.bib` files? As far as I understood your main problem is file encoding: You wouldn't have to parse the data structure for that... (It goes without saying that you don't *have to* accept an answer, so if you feel that your question hasn't been answered properly, you don't need to accept any answer.)

Answer (score 2):

[Biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) by default, uses more strict syntactical validation than BibTeX, and does generally presume that entries are not malformed.

One simple solution may be to use [BibTool](http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/BibTool/en/) to pre-process your BibTeX file, to remove unnecessary entries. There are many ways of doing this, but since you said that entries you cite are valid, you can extract only those using your associated `aux` file:

```
bibtool -x <file.aux>
```

Comment: Ah, and when I properly use the -x command like you suggested, which would only have given well-formed bibtex entries, BibTool fails because not every entry in the aux file is in the .bib file. I normally use bibtex to remind me what citations I still need to look up. :-/

Comment: @JoannaBryson Ah, yeah then this might not work so well, unfortunately. You might be able to use other BibTool options or commands to filter for valid entries, but I don't know off-hand.

Comment: I've put a note on the BibTool github thingy and emailed one of the biblatex people I happen to know, so in the end you may have the winning answer yet, we'll see.